# attachment front end upload in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I got this code from another Homepage and tried to implement it in my functions.php, the upload form works, it uploads the picture, but there´s nothing arriving at wordpress.

Any ideas why? Not so good in debugging to see the fault.

site in question: 
http://web318.login-11.hoststar.at/uni/kleinraum/mitarchpoint/?p=5029
thx in advance

```
//**************************************
// Attachment Insert Form
//**************************************

function insert_attachment_form($postID) {

global $post; $postID = $post->ID;
?>
        <form id="file-form" name="file-form" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                <input type="file" id="async-upload" name="async-upload" />
                <input type="hidden" name="postID" value="<?php echo $postID; ?>" />
                <?php wp_nonce_field('client-file-upload', 'client-file-upload'); ?>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="submit" name="submit" />
        </form>
<?php }

//**************************************
// Process Attachment Form
//**************************************
function process_attachment() {

    global $post; $postID = $post->ID;

        // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
        // because save_post can be triggered at other times
        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['client-file-upload'], 'client-file-upload') ) {
        return $post->ID;
    }
                return $post->ID;

        if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_FILES )) {
                require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
                $id = media_handle_upload('async-upload', $_POST['postID']);
                unset($_FILES);
        }
}

add_action('init', 'process_attachment');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress has provided the example on:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload

Make sure to check if an error occured with the example provided and that you've set the privileges needed on the server.

Comment: thank you! I copied the example and changed some lines to work with captcha instead of privilege-check and it works nicely!

Comment: I know have a little more complex problem. I have a custom post type, to which i would like to attach the attachments, but it doesnt. is there something i  didn´t see? I opened a new topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710473/attachments-to-custom-post-types-frontend